# Finding the Nullspace of a rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving the problems from Gilbert Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra" and the solutions are not explained in details. I'd like to confirm that my logic is correct.

The problem:
If $A$ is 4 by 4 and invertible, describe all vectors in the nullspace of the 4 by 8 matrix
$B = [A A]$.

The solution:
The nullspace of $B = [A A]$ contains all vectors $$
x = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ -y\end{pmatrix}
$$ for $y$ in $R^4$

My intuition is that since A is invertible, its nullspace $N(A)$ consists of only the zero vector. The first 4 columns of the matrix B are the pivot columns and the second 4 - free columns. We can set any arbitrary values for the free variables, so let them be the 4 dimensional vector $y$. Since the elements of $A$ are just concatenated to form matrix $B$, the values of the pivot variables need to cancel those of the free ones, so they need to be the vector $-y$.

Is my logic correct or am I missing any steps?

Comment: Correct but I find the following more complete (though shorter) hence more convincing: $\forall u,v\in\Bbb R^4\quad B\begin{pmatrix} u\\v\end{pmatrix}=A(u+v).$ Since $A$ is invertible, $A(u+v)=0\iff u+v=0.$ Therefore, $N(B)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}u\\-u\end{pmatrix}\mid u\in\Bbb R^4\right\}.$